# Custom region in theme not on front page?

Tags: theming

This is probably (hopefully) a simple question, but I can't figure it out: I'm trying to customize a theme to add a div/region for a "banner" that will display the title of the page on each page...except for the front page. The front page will have a similar "banner" but with different content, more like a promotional thing.

I thought the simplest way to include the banner with the title was simply to move the title rendering in the page.tpl.php:

```
  <div id="banner"><div class="section clearfix">
      <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
      <?php if ($title): ?>
        <h1 class="title" id="page-title">
          <?php print $title; ?>
        </h1>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
  </div></div>
```

This works fine, but then I will get it on the front page as well, and there I want it replaced by a similar banner but with custom content, preferably inserted by a custom block I will create.

How do I do this separately for the home/front page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can differentiate a front page using [drupal_is_front()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7) API

```
<?php if(!drupal_is_front_page()):?>
 <div id="banner"><div class="section clearfix">
      <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
      <?php if ($title): ?>
        <h1 class="title" id="page-title">
          <?php print $title; ?>
        </h1>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
  </div></div> 
<?php endif;?>
```

Or you can create a new TPL `page-front.tpl.php` and omit this div element in that TPL so that it never gets printed. This TPL will be used for front page only.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I like the first idea better. But in case I were to go with a separate template for the front, where do I specify that the front page should use that template?

Comment: Just put the new file in your theme folder and drupal will pick it up (i.e once you clear cache and visit admin/build/themes)

Comment: Ok, I just tried the first suggestion though, and when using it (with or without exclamation mark for is drupal front or is not drupal front, but either way I got a completely unstyled page as a result... so something must have gone wrong with the conditional here...

Comment: Ok i think your css depends on banner and some other IDs that are not getting printed  modify `if($title)` like `if($title && !drupal_is_front())` so that some divs gets printed and remove condition at top and last endif

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. In fact, even this causes the problem:
    <?php if(!drupal_is_front()):?>

    <?php endif;?>

Comment: Ok, I found the problem after Googling a bit: you had accidentally called the function by the wrong name, forgetting the _page, it seems. When I changed it to drupal_is_front_page it worked fine! Thanks!

Comment: Oops sry about that but in my answer i had linked it to the right API on drupal :)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a page--front.tpl.php file in your theme. This file is the same as page.tpl.php but only for the front.

Remember clear cache after the creation of the file.